# Quotient of two uniformly convergent sequences of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f,g$ be continuous on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ with $|g(x)| > 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$. Suppose that $f_n \to f$ and $g_n \to g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$. Prove that $1/g_n$ is defined for large $n$ and $f_n/g_n \to f/g$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.

I have already shown that $1/g_n$ is defined for a large $n$. Note that we can conclude that either $g(x) > 0$ or $g(x) < 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$, which follows by the Intermediate Value Theorem. Suppose $g(x) > 0$. Let $|g(x)| > \varepsilon_0 > k > 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. Since $g_n \to g$ uniformly, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \ge N$ and $x \in [a,b]$, we have $|g_n - g| < \varepsilon_0$. This implies that $0 < k - \varepsilon_0 < g(x) - \varepsilon_0 < g_n$. Thus, we show $1/g_n$ is defined for a large $n$.

I struggle to show $f_n/g_n \to f/g$ uniformly. Any help will be appreciated. I know someone posted the same question but the answer is not complete. I know I need to use $g > k$ and $g_n > k - \varepsilon_0 \, \forall n \ge N$. But I am still struggle to show $|f_n/g_n - f/g| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove that the product of two uniformly convergent sequences in $C([a,b])$ converges uniformly to the product of the limits? You just need to repeat that same proof for the sequences $(f_n)_{n>N}$ and $(1/g_n)_{n>N}$ where $N$ is such that $g_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: No, I don’t. What does $C$ in $C([a,b])$ stand for?

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Do you have any link to the proof for that?

Comment: $C([a,b])$ is the space of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$. You might find the following link to deal with the product case: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052319/uniform-convergence-of-product-of-two-uniformly-convergent-sequences-of-function

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín The example from the link you sent me is a little bit different. They assume $f, and g$ are bounded. I also looked at the comments and some people discussed about $f_n, g_n$ being continuous on $[a, b]$. But this case, we assume $f, g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$ instead. I am still not sure how this help.

Comment: Well continuous functions on a compact interval are always bounded. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín I feel like I am being very stupid. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad I could help! By the way don't fell stupid, part of the learning process in math is to make silly mistakes :)