# Help on product of two convergent sequences of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I saw another answer here somewhere but I got stuck on the last step
If $f_{n}$ and $g_{n}$ are sequences of functions that converge on a compact subset of a metric space, prove that $f_{n}g_{n}$ converges

Based on the definition of uniform convergence,

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for some $\geq N$,

$|g_n(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon$ for some $\geq N$,

we want to show $|f_n(x)g_n(x) - f(x)g(x)|< \epsilon$ so

$|f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f(x)g(x)| = $
$|f_{n}(x)g_{n}(x) - f(x)g_{n}(x) + f(x)g_{n}(x)- f(x)g(x)|$

$= g_{n}(x)|f_{n}(x) - f(x)| + f(x)|g_{n}(x)- g(x)|$
$= g_{n}(x)\epsilon + f(x)\epsilon = (g_{n}(x)+ f(x))\epsilon$

edit:
[uniform convergence of product of two uniformly convergent sequences of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052319/uniform-convergence-of-product-of-two-uniformly-convergent-sequences-of-function)
this is the link I found and I get a bit confused on this part

"Then for each  you have that |()| is bounded for the same reason you have this on real numbers. So we immediately get pointwise convergence. Now take a supremum over  on both sides and see what happens."
I'm not really sure what's going on here?

Now I'm stuck and I don't know how to show that this is smaller than epsilon. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: *“I saw another answer here somewhere ...”* – it is always a good idea to add a link to the answer that you have questions about.

Comment: Since you are asking about uniform convergence on compact sets: Could it be that all functions are assumed to be *continuous?*

Answer (score 1):

If $f_n\to f$ uniformly on the compact set $K$ and all the $f_n$ are continuous, then the sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly bounded. (You should prove this to yourself if you don't already know this.) Using the computation you've already done, there is thus a constant $M$ such that
$$\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f(x)g(x)|&=|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f_n(x)g(x)+f_n(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)| \\
&\leq|f_n(x)g_n(x)-f_n(x)g(x)|+|f_n(x)g(x)-f(x)g(x)| \\
&=|f_n(x)|\cdot|g_n(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|\cdot|f_n(x)-f(x)| \\
&\leq M|g_n(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|\cdot|f_n(x)-f(x)|.
\end{align*}$$
Can you see how to control the left-hand side from here?